# Test HTML5 Ad tag

Tags: jwplayer, vast, jwplayer7, liverail

I am Currently migrating to JW player 7, and I need a test ad tag with 100% fill rate.
In the past I used the [Liverail test tag](http://ad3.liverail.com/?LR_PUBLISHER_ID=1331&LR_CAMPAIGN_ID=229&LR_SCHEMA=vast2), but is seems to have stopped working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I wasn't able to find Liverail test tag but I did find SpotXchange test tag
[http://search.spotxchange.com/vast/2.00/79391?content_page_url={impression_url}&cb={cid}&player_width={pw}&player_height={ph}](http://search.spotxchange.com/vast/2.00/79391?content_page_url=%7Bimpression_url%7D&cb=%7Bcid%7D&player_width=%7Bpw%7D&player_height=%7Bph%7D)

If you try to use it you might need to replace the Aliases wrapped with the curly braces.

This tag is a VPAID 2 tag, and it is able to return both HTML5 and flash ads, if you want VPAID 1 tag just add `VPAID=1` to the URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google test tag from their [Video Suite Inspector page](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector):

```
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dskippablelinear&correlator=
```

When using JW player use the [correlator macro](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1434340-ad-tag-targeting-macros) at the end of the above URL:

```
__random-number__
```

Answer (score 0):

There are others, but I have found http://test-a-tag.com an easy way to test out Video/VAST creatives.